# Can anyone Explain Wizard creation in Magento catalog product step like configurations in Magneto2?

Tags: magento2

I have checked in Magento 2 dev docs where wizard component explain only by frontend point of view But anyone who knows how it is going to work for backend development point of view?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: Not yet...................